# How can I use a user alias with gmail smtp authentification?

Tags: email, drupal-7, smtp, gmail

I am using Drupal 7 and the SMTP module. The Gmail (Apps for work) account uses 2 step verification and an app password so that the website can auth using SMTP. Fine so far.

The problem is that the user account, say `johndoe@domain.com` should not be the from address, but `info@domain.com` should. info is already a working alias for `johndoe`.

We must use `johndoe` to actually authenticate, an alias does not work for this. But, although the from address in debug is `info@domain.com`, in my mail app the sender still seems to be `johndoe@domain.com`.

Any ideas?

Edit: I've read that the Google SMTP service overrides the from address with the user account. Even if the from address is an existing alias?

This is really weird.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem

Comment: @Mirko it wasnt possible, we had to do it differently

Answer (score 9):

Please try adding alias email address in gmail.

Open gmail => Setting => Accounts => Send email as: => Add another email address

Gmail will send confirmation code to the alias email. After you add the alias address, gmail smtp will accept "from" parameter with your alias address.

Comment: This works, even if the alias is an internal email. It's not intuitive, but you need to do this even if you add the delivery alias via the admin panel, then when you send via SMTP, google will respect the `from:` setting instead of changing it to the login account

Answer (score -1):

if I understood you, if you want to use the account (johndoe@domain.com) to authenticate, but you do not want it to be shown as a sender, and the sender should be (info@domain.com), then you must follow the following Steps.

It is more than obvious that you must be a GSuite administrator.
First you enable third-party authentication, go to:

```
Google GSuite Security=>
basic configuration=> 
Unsecured applications=>
(click here) Access the settings of unsafe applications=>
Enable access for all users to unsafe applications (not recommended)

Second, in your application for sending mail do this:
Sender Address: info@domain.com
User: johndoe@domain.com
Server: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465
Encryption: ssl
Password: yourpassowrdaccount
```

Exampple: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0X8J.png